# How many codes can be formed from three letters (A-Z) followed by two digits ($0$-$9$)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

#### Problem:

> A code consists of 3 letters followed by 2 digits. How many codes can we create if a)repetition is allowed b)repetition is not allowed?

#### Attempt:

The code should looks like this **LLLDD** (L for letter and D for  digit) so if repetition is allowed, the number of possible codes is
$$(26^3)(10)^2$$
and if repetition is not allowed the number of possible  codes is
$$26 \mathrm{ P }3 \times 10 \mathrm{ P }2.$$

#### My concern:

How does $(26^3)(10)^2$ or $26 \mathrm{ P }3 \times 10 \mathrm{ P }2$ guarantee that the code has the correct pattern (**LLLDD**) and not other patterns like **LDLDL**, **LLDDL**, it's what permutations do after all (order is important), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you are counting the number of ways to create **LLL** and **DD** separately. Since there is only one way to put them together to create **LLLDD**, multiply and you're done.

If you wanted to count **LDLDL** and **LLDDL**, among other arrangements, you would need to *choose* the positions of the letters. Or of the numbers. Either way, it's an additional multiplication by ten.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to count LDLDL and LLDDL?

Comment: or even give me a reference on how they are counted

Comment: @AmirWG There are $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways to select the positions of the letters. The remaining positions will be numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative explanation.

> how does $(26^3)(10)^2$ or ${}26 \mathrm{ P }3 \times 10 \mathrm{ P }2$ guarantee that the code
> has the correct pattern (**LLLDD**) and not other patterns like **LDLDL** , **LLDDL** , it's what permutations do after all (order is important), right?

The formulas do **not** guarantee the pattern.  However, the formulas are **still** correct.  The original question is to enumerate the number of ways that the pattern **LLLDD** can occur.  The formulas are accurate, under the **assumption** that your attention is **confined** to the LLLDD pattern.

The fact that the formulas may also be correct for other patterns is totally irrelevant.